# How do I change the document root for lighttpd?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, webserver, lubuntu, lighttpd

I am trying to change my lighttpd configuration as follows:

I have a 500GB ext4 formatted hard disk attached to my server via USB. I would like to either

a) Change my lighttpd server's document root to /media/adam/Server/http (a real folder on my hard drive)

or

b) Symlink that same folder to `/var/www` and have it work properly (e.g. going to `localhost/http/somefile.html` would have `somefile.html` show up).

`/media/adam/Server/http` is set to `chown www-data:www-data`, `chmod 775`.
When browsing to a file, I get `error 403 Access Denied`.